# Math word problem. Any help is appreciated.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

A math student writes a proof of the derivative of a certain trigonometric function. The last line she writes before stating her conclusion is...

$\dfrac{d}{d\theta} \left(\sin\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) \right)=\cos\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

These are the graphs of $\sin\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$\sin\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ = http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28theta%2Bpi%2F2%29&lk=4

$\cos\left(\theta +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$= http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28theta%2Bpi%2F2%29&lk=4&num=1

Hence, write the statement of her conclusion beginning with the word, "Therefore...".

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: Sorry, it's not exactly a problem. I'm just unsure of how to write the statement of conclusion?

Comment: What statement, and what conclusion?

Comment: Sounds like her teacher wanted to ask a question about proofs without actually asking the students to prove something, but didn't do a very good job of writing the question in a way that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "read" the statement $\frac d{d\theta} \sin\left(\theta+\frac \pi 2\right) = \cos\left(\theta + \frac\pi 2\right)$ as

"The derivative of sine theta plus pi over two by theta is cos theta plus pi over two"

You should never write it out like that, it's how it's pronounced, and the maths is how it is spelt.

So when you conclude your proof   you might want to add a word or two to make it sound more natural, especially if it's on its own at the end as a one sentance paragraph.

You might say

"Therefore, $\frac d{d\theta} \sin\left(\theta+\frac \pi 2\right) = \cos\left(\theta + \frac\pi 2\right)$."

or it might be better to say

"We have calculated: $\frac d{d\theta} \sin\left(\theta+\frac \pi 2\right) = \cos\left(\theta + \frac\pi 2\right)$.

It doesn't really matter there isn't a right answer. Notice that the punctuation is the same as it would be if you wrote out the sentence longhand. The only really important thing is to remember the full stop at the end.